# REGEX does not match everything from my string

Tags: regex, string

Any ideas why this regex doesn't match everything from my string?
 (I want it to match discord.gg/XUGswJ)
[image: regex match]

Comment: If it's .NET, you could write either way: 1) `discord\.gg\/.+(?i)[a-z]` or 2) `discord\.gg\/.+[A-za-z]`

Comment: / does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

`[a-z]` means lowercase letters. You probably want `[a-zA-Z]` to include uppercase.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark your answer as correct when I have access.